# "Unauthozied acceess" error when I access influxDB from my python code with token

Tags: python, influxdb, unauthorized

I am facing an issue.
I did a tutorial of influxDB
The tutorial provides python code with token for accessing influxDB.
However, It's failed and show "Unauthoried access" error message.

Please help me.

```
import influxdb_client, os, time
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

bucket="test"

token = os.environ.get("INFLUXDB_TOKEN")

org = "Test-org"
url = "http://localhost:8086"

client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org)

write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

for value in range(5):
  point = (
    Point("main") #Measurement
    .tag("ser", "m")    #tagname, tagvalue
    .field("s", 700)    #fileld1, value
  )
  write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=point)
  time.sleep(1) # separate points by 1 second
```

and the error message is as below,

```
influxdb_client.rest.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json; 
charset=utf-8', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'OSS', 'X-Influxdb-Version': 'v2.7.1', 'X- 
Platform-Error-Code': 'unauthorized', 'Date': 'Wed, 14 Jun 2023 06:27:07 GMT', 
'Content-Length': '55'})
HTTP response body: {"code":"unauthorized","message":"unauthorized access"}
```